# Windows Uninstall key

Tags: windows, registry

I want to ask regarding below key,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{D524405E-3AA5-454A-A996-38EBA64F757C}
```

From above, we can see the key is **{D524405E-3AA5-454A-A996-38EBA64F757C}**, this key is for our company application.

However, just want to know is this key is a unique number? If it is unique, I can see this key value is all a same value when I install the application in another server or VM.

When we install the application, does this key will automatically generated or define by the developer?

Comment: What does powershell and batch file have to do with this? And what exactly do you mean by unique?

Comment: If that key is for you company application, your company is best suited to answer that question. It's a GUID (UUID) and the idea behind a GUID is that it's used to uniquely identify something but in the end and ill advised, no one is stopping your company  to use that GUID for more than one thing.